# How to call class which Extends Asynctask Class from AlertDialogManager

Tags: android

I am Making a Login Activity,In that I use three button ,while Click on Login Button,I  call a Alert Dialog where I  use SignIn xml file for layout for   alertdialog manager,where I use two  text box for username & Password &  a button,when click on button ,it call  a  class  which extends the AsyncTask Class,there I  Use Shared Prefernce  & Json for the Login ,but  in LogCat error comes   that is

```
AndroidRuntime(6179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(6179): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at com.example.ReferenceRewards.LogInActivity$BackgroundTask.onPreExecute(LogInActivity.java:489)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at com.example.ReferenceRewards.LogInActivity$2.onClick(LogInActivity.java:156)
/AndroidRuntime(6179):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
AndroidRuntime(6179):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

//  &  my Login Activity Class code  is

```
package com.example.ReferenceRewards;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogInActivity extends Activity{
    ImageView imagereferencerewards;
    TextView txtview,forgot_pass;
    Button  btnsignin;
    Button  btnjoinus;
    Button btnloginwithfb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        imagereferencerewards  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash_icon);
        txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btnsignin =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
        btnjoinus =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnjoinus);
        btnloginwithfb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnloginusingfb);
        forgot_pass =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgot_pass);

        SpannableString fpContent = new SpannableString("Forgot your password?");
        fpContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, fpContent.length(), 0);
        forgot_pass.setText(fpContent);


        forgot_pass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "forgot password,enter mail id & Mobile No  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                d.setContentView(R.layout.forgotpassword);
                d.setTitle("FORGOT YOUR  PASSWORD");
                d.setCancelable(true);
                EditText edtfemail=(EditText)  d.findViewById(R.id.edtfemail);
                EditText edtfmob = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtfmobile);
                Button  btnfsubmit  =(Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnfsubmit);
                btnfsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                d.show();
            }
        });

    }

        public void signin(View v) {



            final AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
            //SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            String TAG = "LOGINACTIVITY";
            final ConnectionDetector cd;
            final SharedPreferences pref;

             final String TAG_USER_ID = "userId";

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);
            pref = LogInActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(LogInActivity.this
                    .getResources().getString(R.string.pref_title),
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);

               d.setContentView(R.layout.signin);

               d.setTitle("SIGN IN");

               d.setCancelable(true);

               final EditText edtEmail = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtemail);

               final EditText edtPass = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);

               try {
                   edtEmail.setText(pref.getString(this.getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.pref_username), ""));
                    edtPass.setText(pref.getString(this.getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.pref_password), ""));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.v(TAG, "-ERROR-LINE NO ");
            }

               Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);

               b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Get username, password from EditText
                        //String username = edtEmail.getText().toString();
                        //String password = edtPass.getText().toString();


                        //if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0)
                        if (edtEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                        {
                            edtEmail.setError("Username required");
                            edtEmail.requestFocus();
                        } else if (edtPass.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            edtPass.setError("Password required");
                            edtPass.requestFocus();
                        } else {

                            //if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                            if(cd.isConnectingToInternet()){
                                new BackgroundTask().execute("");

                                /*
                                 * Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                 * HomeActivity.class); startActivity(i); finish();
                                 */

                            } 
                        else
                        {
                                showAlertDialog(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                                        "Please connect to internet.", false);
                            }
                        }

                   }

               });



               //
                /*class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                    }*/

/*             @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
            private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

                    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String result =null;
                        String url="";
                        HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
                        try {

                            url=getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.base_url)
                                    + "login?username="
                                    + URLEncoder.encode(edtEmail.getText().toString()
                                            .trim(), "utf-8")
                                    + "&password="
                                    + URLEncoder.encode(edtPass.getText().toString()
                                            .trim(), "utf-8");
                            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                            Log.v("LOGIN-URL", url);

                            HttpResponse httpresponse =  httpclient.execute(httpget);
                            Log.i("LoginActivity", httpresponse.getStatusLine().toString());

                            HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();

                            /*if (entity != null) {
                                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                                result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                                // now you have the string representation of the HTML
                                // request
                                instream.close();
                            }
                            if(httpentity != null){

                                InputStream is = httpentity.getContent();
                                result = convertStreamToString(is);
                                is.close();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                        //return null;
                        return result;
                    }

                    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //return null;

                        BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        try {
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally {
                            try {
                                is.close();
                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                e2.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        return sb.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //super.onPostExecute(result);
                        pd.cancel();
                        if (result!= null) {
                            Log.v("Login Response", "" + result);
                            int userId = 0;
                            JSONObject resultObj;
                            try {
                                resultObj = new JSONObject(result);
                                JSONObject referencerewardsObject = resultObj
                                        .getJSONObject("referencerewardsSignIn");

                                userId = referencerewardsObject.getInt(TAG_USER_ID);

                                Log.v(TAG_USER_ID, "" + userId);

                                if (userId <= 0) {
                                    showAlertDialog(context, "Failure", "Not Valid User",
                                            false);
                                } else {

                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                    if (staySignedInCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                                        editor.putString(
                                                context.getResources().getString(
                                                        R.string.pref_stay_signed_in),
                                                "Yes");
                                if (userId<0) {
                                    showAlertDialog(getBaseContext(), "FAILURE", "Not Valid User", false);
                                } else {
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                                    editor.putString(
                                            getBaseContext().getResources().getString(
                                                    R.string.pref_userId),
                                            String.valueOf(userId));
                                    editor.commit();

                                    Intent HomeDashIntent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,
                                            HomeDashBoard.class);
                                    startActivity(HomeDashIntent);
                                    finish();

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                         else if (result == null) {
                                showAlertDialog(getBaseContext(), "Failure",
                                        "Wrong Username or Password.", false);
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        pd.setTitle("Plaese wait");
                        pd.setMessage("Signng In...");
                        pd.setCancelable(true);
                        pd.show();

                    }

                }  */


             //
               d.show();

             }

        private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
            ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());

            SharedPreferences pref;

            static final String TAG_USER_ID = "userId";

            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            /*LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.signin,null, true);
             void setContentView(v);*/

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //return null;
                setContentView(R.layout.signin);
                EditText edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);

                EditText edtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
                String result =null;
                String url="";
                HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {

                    url=getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.base_url)
                            + "login?username="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(edtEmail.getText().toString()
                                    .trim(), "utf-8")
                            + "&password="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(edtPass.getText().toString()
                                    .trim(), "utf-8");
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                    Log.v("LOGIN-URL", url);

                    HttpResponse httpresponse =  httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", httpresponse.getStatusLine().toString());

                    HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();

                    /*if (entity != null) {
                        // A Simple JSON Response Read
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                        result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                        // now you have the string representation of the HTML
                        // request
                        instream.close();
                    }*/
                    if(httpentity != null){

                        InputStream is = httpentity.getContent();
                        result = convertStreamToString(is);
                        is.close();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                //return null;
                return result;


            }

            private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //return null;

                BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onPostExecute(result);
                //
                pd.cancel();
                if (result!= null) {
                    Log.v("Login Response", "" + result);
                    int userId = 0;
                    JSONObject resultObj;
                    try {
                        resultObj = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONObject referencerewardsObject = resultObj
                                .getJSONObject("referencerewardsSignIn");

                        userId = referencerewardsObject.getInt(TAG_USER_ID);

                        Log.v(TAG_USER_ID, "" + userId);


                        if (userId<0) {
                            showAlertDialog(getBaseContext(), "FAILURE", "Not Valid User", false);
                        } else {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                            editor.putString(
                                    getBaseContext().getResources().getString(
                                            R.string.pref_userId),
                                    String.valueOf(userId));
                            editor.commit();

                            Intent HomeDashIntent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this,
                                    HomeDashBoard.class);
                            startActivity(HomeDashIntent);
                            finish();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                 else if (result == null) {
                        showAlertDialog(getBaseContext(), "Failure",
                                "Wrong Username or Password.", false);
                    }

                //
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onPreExecute();
                //setContentView(R.layout.signin);  
                pd.setTitle("Plaese wait");
                pd.setMessage("Signng In...");
                pd.setCancelable(true);
                pd.show();

            }

        }


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
                Boolean status) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            // alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success :
            // R.drawable.fail);

            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }



        public void joinus(View v) {

            final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.signup);
            d.setTitle("JOIN US");
            d.setCancelable(true);

            EditText edtname=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtname);
            EditText edtaddress=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtaddress);
            EditText edtpass=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
            EditText edtcity=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtcity);
            EditText edtmobile=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtmobile);
            Button b = (Button ) d.findViewById(R.id.btnsignup);

            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    d.dismiss();

                }
            });
            d.show();

        }

        /*public void forgotpassword(View v) {

            final  Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
            d.setContentView(R.layout.forgotpassword);
            d.setTitle("FORGOT YOUR  PASSWORD");
            d.setCancelable(true);
            EditText edtfemail=(EditText)  d.findViewById(R.id.edtfemail);
            EditText edtfmob = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtfmobile);
            Button  btnfsubmit  =(Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnfsubmit);
            btnfsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
            d.show();   
        }*/

        /*public void loginwtfb(View v) {
            final  Dialog d =  new Dialog(this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.forgotpassword);
            d.setTitle("FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD");
            d.setCancelable(true);
            EditText  edtemail=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtfemail);
            EditText  edtmob=(EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.edtfmobile);
            Button btnfsub = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.btnfsubmit);

            btnfsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
            d.show();
        }*/



}
//  & XML file   of Login is 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


                <LinearLayout`enter code here`
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"`enter code here`
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/splash_icon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:text="SIGN UP-SELECT SHOP-SHOP-REPORT-GET PAID!!!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsignin"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnjoinus"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnjoinus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:onClick="signin"
        android:text="SIGN IN" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnjoinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnloginusingfb"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnloginusingfb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnsignin"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="joinus"
        android:text="JOIN US" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnloginusingfb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnjoinus"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook" 
        android:onClick="loginwtfb"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/forgot_pass"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnjoinus"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/btnloginusingfb"
                            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                            android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
                            android:textColor="@color/links_color"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
//  &  XML file for sign up is 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtemail"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtpassword"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>


            <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsubmit"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your concern

```
new BackgroundTask().execute();
```

And put your progress dialog code in PreExecute() like this

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
```

UDATE::

Use AsyncTaskClass as fallows

```
class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpget = new HttpGet(StaticVars.all_service_url);

            try {
                httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                System.out.println("httpresponse" + httpresponse);

                is = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                sb = new StringBuilder();

                String recievingDataFromServer = null;
                while ((recievingDataFromServer = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.i("CHECK WHILE", "CHECK WHILE");
                    sb.append(recievingDataFromServer);
                }

                myJsonString = sb.toString();

                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("modify", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("myJsonString", myJsonString);

                editor.commit();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (myJsonString.length() > 0) {

                try {

                    myJsonObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
                    myJsonArray = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("keyword");

                    for (int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject objJson = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        name = objJson.getString("name");

                        recognition_id = objJson.getInt("recognition_id");
                        ServicesModel sm = new ServicesModel();
                        //name = name.replaceAll(name, "<font color='red'>$0</font>");
                        /*Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( etselect.getText().toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( name );
                        name = matcher.replaceAll( "\0" );*/

                        sm.name = name;
                        sm.recognisationId = recognition_id;
                        sm.recognisationName = recognisationArray[recognition_id];
                        serviceArray.add(sm);
                        /*if(Arrays.asList(serviceArray).contains(textView.getText().toString())){

                        }*/
                    }


                    ArrayAdapter<ServicesModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ServicesModel>(
                            SearchActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, serviceArray);
                    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    //textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
                    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            ServicesModel sm = (ServicesModel) arg0
                                    .getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                            service_name = sm.name;
                            service_recog_id = sm.recognisationId;

                            textView.setText("");
                            textView.append(sm.name);
                            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // ====================================================================================
                /////   PEFORMING STUFF FOR BOTH KEYWORD AND LOCATION OVER HERE ..
                // ====================================================================================

                try {

                    nmyJsonObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
                    nmyJsonArray = nmyJsonObject.getJSONArray("location");

                    for (int i = 0; i < nmyJsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject nobjJson = nmyJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        city_name = nobjJson.getString("city_name");
                        country_name = nobjJson.getString("country_name");

                        LocationModel lm = new LocationModel();
                        lm.City_Name = city_name;
                        lm.Country_Name = country_name;
                        locationArray.add(lm);

                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<LocationModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LocationModel>(
                            SearchActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locationArray);
                    ltextView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    ltextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            LocationModel lm = (LocationModel) arg0
                                    .getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                            city_name = lm.City_Name;
                            country_name = lm.Country_Name;
                        }
                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line `ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());`
 in your BackgroundTask class to, `ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(LogInActivity.this);`